# spring httpinvoker error (org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException) on google appengine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, httpinvoker

I've been trying to set up a httpinvoker based server on my google appengine account. I followed instructions given in spring documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please review my code below and let me know whats wrong.

My web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherSe rvlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My remoting-servlet.xml

```
<bean name="/AccountService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.Ht tpInvokerServiceExporter">
<property name="service" ref="accountService"/>
<property name="serviceInterface" value="app.server.AccountService"/>
</bean>
```

My client xml:

```
<bean id="httpInvokerProxy" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.Ht tpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="serviceUrl" value="http://<google appid>.appspot.com/remoting/AccountService"/>
<property name="serviceInterface" value="app.server.AccountService"/>
</bean>
```

My client side code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springClientConfig .xml");
AccountService testService = (AccountService) applicationContext.getBean("httpInvokerProxy");
String retVal = testService.getAccounts("test");
System.out.println(retVal);
}
```

I keep getting a exception (org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException): 
Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://googleappId.appspot.com/remoting/AccountService]; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Did not receive successful HTTP response: status code = 500, status message = [Internal Server Error]

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to fix it by any change?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `app.server.AccountService` is a class or interface,it should be a interface,if it's a class ,500 will happen.